# SQL Server ML. External Python Script: Access Denied Error

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, machine-learning, microsoft-machine-learning-server

I am trying to make something useful with SQL Machine Learning Services and Python.

I am trying to include an external python script into the SQL code. For now I am testing on SQL Server Management Studio on SQL Server 2019 Dev Edition.

Folloing [Niels Berglund](https://nielsberglund.com/2018/03/07/microsoft-sql-server-r-services---sp_execute_external_script---i/), excelent article I am doing:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language =N'Python', 
@script=N'
import os
os.system("C:\TEMP\ml.py")
OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
print("Say Hello from SQL Server Management Studio")
',
@input_data_1 =N'SELECT 42' 
WITH RESULT SETS (([TheAnswer] int not null));  
GO
```

My `ml.py` script is just this:

```
#!"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\python.exe"
print("Say Hello from the external script")
```

When I run my T-SQL script I get this:

```
STDERR message(s) from external script: 
Access Denied

STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
Say Hello from SQL Management Studio


(1 row affected)

Completion time: 2020-12-23T08:51:59.9264251-05:00
```

I made sure the script has what I believe are the right permissions:

[image]

I even tried just assigning **full control** to **Everyone**. I do not see any error on either SQL or Windows Event Viewer.

I have tried with the following variations of `os.system()` without any success:

```
os.system("\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Lib\cust\ml.py\"")
```

```
os.system("\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\python.exe\" \"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Lib\cust\ml.py\"")
```

```
os.system("python.exe \"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Lib\cust\ml.py\"")
```

```
os.system("python.exe C:\TEMP\ml.py")
```

Any idea is very welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: I think I found the answer I was looking for already in Niel's post (https://nielsberglund.com/2018/03/07/microsoft-sql-server-r-services---sp_execute_external_script---i/) . It would be ```@script = N'source("/path/to/my/script/my_python_script.py")';```

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using? Here are a couple of links I have saved on this topic. I haven't went down this road yet of using Python on SQL Server, but I am about to.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/package-management/install-additional-python-packages-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/package-management/install-additional-python-packages-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you @JasonCook for your comment. I am using SQL Server 2017. I am close to a solution but I am facing a different problem.  I am updating the question to reflect it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make this work by:

- Passing *python /script location/* to `os.system`.
- Placing the script in the `cust` folder inside python services in my SQL Server instance.  I am not overly happy about this. It seems to be a question of folder permissions but I much I tried to mimic them on another more convenient folder, I was not able to make it run successfully.

This is how it looks:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language =N'Python', 
@script=N'
import os
os.system("python \"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Lib\cust\ml.py\"")

OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
print("Say Hello from SQL Server Management Studio")
',
@input_data_1 =N'SELECT 42' 
WITH RESULT SETS (([TheAnswer] int not null));  
GO
```